# I need help adding a loop to repeat my code four times

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is the code I am working with. I am new to programming and I know I need to use a loop to have the set velocities I have repeat four times, I am just not sure how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
package Code.simpleOutput;
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;


public class GeoPattern {

         public static void main(final String[] args)
       {
         Finch myFinch = new Finch();

         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255,1000);
         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,0,800);
         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255,1000);
         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,0,800);
         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255,1000);
         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,0,800);
         myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,225,1000);


         myFinch.quit();
          System.exit(0);
       }

}
```

Comment: should read some java tutorials =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a for loop.

```
for(int x = 4; x >0; x--) {

     myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255,1000);
     myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,0,800);
}
```

You need to explain your objective more though.

This code will set the wheel velocities to `255,255,1000`, then immediately change them back to `255,0,800`, and do that four times.

Aren't you instead trying to switch between them, which would require some kind of pause, timer, or test?

In the meantime, you really should peruse the Oracle documentation for Java, and in particular the control structures: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

If you are new to Java, Exceptions and Threads are probably a bit of a harsh takeoff, but bear with me:

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
```

This instruction will make your code pause for 4 seconds (it takes milliseconds as an argument).
In order to use that "pause" code, you'll need to declare that your method, here, `main`:

```
 throws InterruptedException
```

Why? Because, if you had several "Threads" in your application, another Thread might interrupt yours while it is sleeping. *Basically, say "hey, I need to calculate something, since you're asleep I'm going to borrow the processor, I'll give it back later"*

Since you only have one Thread, you don't bother, you just declare that it might theorically happen, and you're good to go.

In the event that you wanted to switch the speeds and see it happen, the code becomes:

```
package Code.simpleOutput;
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;


public class GeoPattern {

     public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException // because it contains a sleep call
   {
     Finch myFinch = new Finch();

    for(int x = 4; x >0; x--) 
    {
      Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep a second
      myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255,1000);
      Thread.sleep(1000); // sleep another second
      myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,0,800);
     }
     myFinch.quit();
     System.exit(0);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255,1000);
    myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,0,800);
}
```

Comment: Heh, for the same price of a question, OP gets a loop up and a loop down ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    //code to repeat goes here
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html